# Arrangement of points, lines, and planes

Tags: co.combinatorics, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Is it possible to construct a finite nontrivial arrangement of points, lines, and planes in 3-dimensional Euclidean space with the following properties?

- every line is incident with four points and four planes
- for every point incident to a plane (of which there is at least one), exactly four lines are both incident to that plane and that point

Comment: You are asking for every line to be incident with $a$ points, every line to be incident with $b$ planes, and every point on a plane to be jointly incident with exactly $c$ lines, for $(a,b,c)=(4,4,4)$. Do you have solutions for $(a,b,c)=(4,4,3)$ or $(a,b,c)=(4,3,4)$ or $(a,b,c)=(3,4,4)$?

Comment: No, I’m only interested in cases where all three are equal and even.

Comment: Do you care whether the arrangement is finite or infinite?

Comment: I want it to be finite.

Comment: Do you want to add some non-triviality conditions to rule out, e.g., no points are incident to any planes?

Comment: That sounds like a good idea.

Comment: You added the word "nontrivial". But what does that mean? Would you accept an answer which is the following: Take four arbitrary (distinct) planes. Take as many lines as you like, arbitrary except not parallel to any of the planes. And finally on each line choose four arbitrary points, just not on any of the planes (you can use fewer total points if they are at intersections of lines). This way each line is incident with four points and four planes, and there aren't any points incident to planes so the second condition is vacuously satisfied.

Comment: Does the existence of such a non-trivial arrangement imply a $(4,4)$-configuration in the Euclidean plane?  I know Grünbaum-RIgby configuration with this property.

Comment: Find a configuration $(18_4)$ in [Bokowski, J., & Schewe, L. (2013). On the finite set of missing geometric configurations (n4). Computational Geometry, 46(5), 532-540].  It is nicely realized with triangles and infinity points, might be useful for the construction here.